# How do I specify the Selenium Hub URL when running Serenity tests from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to use the Serenity BDD testing framework with JUnit, instead of using Selenium directly, but I can't figure out how give the Serenity-managed `WebDriver` instance the URL of my Selenium Hub in a way that works for running tests from Eclipse (with "Run As > JUnit Test").

Using `@Managed` with `driver="remote"` correctly tries to create a `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver` instance...

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class SerenityIT {
    @Managed(driver="remote") WebDriver browser;
    //[...]
}
```

... but this fails with

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null at
>   java.net.URL.(URL.java:532) ~[na:1.8.0_151]

which isn't surprising because there is no URL specified. So how should I pass the Selenium Hub URL?

Comment: Have you seen this guide: http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_running_remote_tests? You can specify the remote url in properties file

Comment: @AldoSuwandi Yes, I have. Since it only contains examples with Maven, it doesn't lead me to think serenity.properties is loaded when running individual tests from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns our Serenity also loads `serenity.properties` when running tests from Eclipse, even though this is neither documented nor implied. I wrote one and Serenity found it, which is confirmed by logs in the console:

> DEBUG [net.thucydides.core.util.PropertiesFileLocalPreferences:115] -
>   LOADING LOCAL PROPERTIES FROM
>   /integration-testing/serenity.properties

Selenium Hub's URL can then be provided as documented with `webdriver.remote.url`. Below are the properties I'm currently using, with an example of passing Firefox preferences.

```
webdriver.driver=remote
webdriver.remote.driver=firefox
webdriver.remote.url=http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
webdriver.timeouts.implicitlywait=10000
firefox.preferences=devtools.jsonview.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also configure it in *serenity.conf* file

So something like that;

```
# Remote
webdriver {
  driver = remote
  remote {
      url="http://localhost:4445/wd/hub"
      driver=chrome
  }
}
```